# Add horizontal reference line to Google charts' LineChart

Tags: google-visualization

I'm using [Google visualization's LineChart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart) to display some data (it works).

The chart shows performance tests results and those results should *not* be over some value (eg. response time should not be more than 20ms). Si I'd like to draw that maximum (an horizontal line I guess) without having to add a new (dummy) series of data.

Is that possible?

Thanks a lot,

Alban

Comment: Just a thought: if you don't need the baseline of the vertical axis for anything else, you could set it to your threshold value to get a highlighted horizontal gridline.

Comment: @dlaliberte, wouldn't that affect the rest of the gridlines?

Comment: The baseline is just one value that gets highlighted with a bold gridline, and it doesn't have to also be a regular gridline.  If the baseline value is not otherwise a gridline, then, yes, it is possible it could affect automatically calculated gridlines, but I haven't found a case yet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you can't add another line without adding another series of data, but you don't have to add it manually - a DataView would suffice to calculate it for you:

```
var maxResponseTime = 20;
var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
view.setColumns([0, 1[, 2, 3, 4.... /* specify all of your existing columns here */, {
    type: 'number',
    calc: function () {
        return maxResponseTime;
    }
}]);

var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(...);
chart.draw(view, {
    // options
    series: {
        // "n" should be the series index of the max line
        // typically this is column index - 1,
        // so if you have one domain column, one data series
        // and the max line, it would be:
        1: {
            visibleInLegend: false, // set this if you don't want it in the legend
            enableInteractivity: false // set this if you don't want the line to spawn tooltips
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: It seems to do the job. Thanks a lot!